# How can I use a part to create projected geometries in another part?

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I have a part modeled, and I wish to create a complimentary part. One option is to create an offset plane and project geometries, but for organisational purposes I would like to keep the files distinct.

How can I use this part's geometry in another part's sketches?

I tried selecting and copying the existing part to a new part to use as a guide, but this didn't work.

I've resorted to just making a copy of the file for now and using an offset plane, and then hiding the copy — but this seems like a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

- Start in the first part file.
- Open up a sketch on the surface face you'd like to use.
- Use the proejct geometry command, then use the copy command to highlight all features.
- Go into the second part file and open a sketch.
- Right click and choose paste.

To move the now pasted projected geometry, simply use the move command.